# how can i initialize an object

Tags: c++, object, initialization

The point is to **initialize a pointer to a Mystic object with the value "beep"** any idea?

```
class Mystic { 
private:
 string label;
 Mystic(string & newlbl) { setLabel (newlbl)};
public:
 void setLabel(string newlbl){label = newlbl;}
 Mystic() : label(){};
};
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
...    //i tried this
       //string *p1 = new string("beep");
      //Mystic myst(p1);
}
```

Comment: Since this question about confusing pointers and references, and displays some anti-patterns, it might be best answered with a good C++ book. Perhaps you should have a look at the [C++ recommended book list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/).

Answer (score 1):

The constructor that takes a string is not public, so you can't use it.  Instead use the default constructor and then the setLabel method.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  Mystic m;
  m.setLabel("beep");
  Mystic* p = &m;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Constructor you trying to use its a private , and you can only access public one , so you have to make that constructor public , or if you want to use public default constructor and initialize default value `Mystic() : label("default"){}`